# How can I get the total likes count of a photo (include shares) on Facebook?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-fql

Example:

The photo contains 3 likes and 2 shares.

The shares contais plus 2 likes each. Total 7 likes.

However, when I use:

https://graph.facebook.com/id_photo/likes

or

https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=select%20like_info%20from%20photo%20where%20object_id=id_photo

I only get 3 likes of original photo.

Comment: The Likes Open Graph only counts the number of Likes in object being queried.

Comment: Shivan, Do you know any way to solve the problem using other alternative?

Comment: No you can't. You can get the share count from `link_stat` table via FQL, but you can't get the post ID of shared posts.

Comment: The photo in question is of a page. Through the admin panel it is possible to see the amount of people reached by example. It would be possible to obtain information from the administrative panel via API?

Comment: Photos in Page album, No ; Posts in Page, Yes. (only if you have enough likes and permission to gain access to full Insight)